# Audio and video streaming from web server

Tags: ios, ios4, video-streaming

I have been working on the audio and video streaming, where I have to pick a file from remote server and then play it on iPhone but I am not getting the results. When I run the project the error generates saying it cannot play it.

I have also tried "iphoneStreamingPlayer" application available at link

http://projectswithlove.com/projects/iPhoneStreamingPlayer.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I didn't get any solution to this issue. One thing I got to know during searching is that Apple does not directly support it but there are a few private libraries that supports RTSP streaming but are not supported by Apple.